# Validating Ninject Bindings

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-web-api2, ninject

I've got a WebAPI project that uses Ninject for its DI.
I would like to validiate/confirm that the bindings have all worked, but the code I've come up with smells a bit.  So I would like to know if there is a better way.

The caller:

```
    private IKernel CreateKernel()
    {
        var kernel = new StandardKernel();
        kernel.Load(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = kernel.Get<System.Web.Http.Dependencies.IDependencyResolver>();

        try
        {
            RegisterServices(kernel);
            CheckServices(kernel);
            return kernel;
        }
        catch (ActivationException ex)
        {
            if (kernel != null)
                kernel.Dispose();

            log.Fatal(ex);
            throw;
        }
        catch
        {
            if (kernel != null)
                kernel.Dispose();
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Then:

```
    private void RegisterServices(StandardKernel kernel)
    {
        kernel.Bind<Func<IKernel>>().ToMethod(context => () => new Bootstrapper().Kernel);
        kernel.Bind<IHttpModule>().To<HttpApplicationInitializationHttpModule>();
```

snipped to avoid SO too much code warning!

```
    private void CheckServices(StandardKernel kernel)
    {
        ILog ilog = kernel.TryGetAndThrowOnInvalidBinding<ILog>();
        IDBHandler idbhandler = kernel.TryGetAndThrowOnInvalidBinding<IDBHandler>();
        IUserManagementService user = kernel.TryGetAndThrowOnInvalidBinding<IUserManagementService>();
        IMassService mass = kernel.TryGetAndThrowOnInvalidBinding<IMassService>();
        IPPSService pps = kernel.TryGetAndThrowOnInvalidBinding<IPPSService>();

        ilog = null;
        idbhandler = null;
        ambient = null;
        auth = null;

        pps = null;
        mass = null;
        user = null;

        log.Info("Ninject Kernel Bindings checked.");
    }
```

Comment: Well, I don't see why you would want to do this. You are attempting to get a binding and throw an exception if something goes wrong. If you don't check like this, your application will encounter an error when it tries to get a binding and will also throw an exception with a pretty detailed dump of why it failed to activate anyways. I can understand you wanting to eagerly load them for the sake of verification, but It does not seem necessary.

Comment: @JuanR well I was wanting to catch it early as it wasn't obvious that binding failure was the cause later on.  Ok of course that might be the result of bad code in other places.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why you would need to check the bindings like you are doing in production code. What are you going to do if the binding check fails?

Instead I would check them with unit tests. I use the following approach, which is to loop through each of the bindings in my module and try to instantiate them:

```
[Test]
public void AllModuleBindingsTest()
{
    var kernel = new StandardKernel(new MyNinjectModule())
    foreach (var binding in new MyNinjectModule().Bindings)
    {
        var result = kernel.Get(binding.Service);
        Assert.NotNull(result, $"Could not get {binding.Service}");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks I'll look into using the Ninject Module approach, and also moving this into a UT.

Comment: I don't know how useful this would be. I imagine it requires you to register any referenced DLLs in the unit testing project?